# Wordpress header not displaying correctly on safari browser (logo disappears and the background gets stretched)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari, elementor

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgH38.png)
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQLaQ.png)

Temp url: handelen.no

I've tried the site in multiple browsers without issues, but Safari really doesn't like the website header.
Website is designed with Elementor, by me, so it might be something ive screwed up.

If I refresh the website in Safari its looking normal again, but when you browse it happens again until refresh.

Would appreciate it if someone could give me any pointers!

Ive tried changing the header logo from webp to png, thinking that might be an issue, but realized that the footer logo is webp aswell, so that did not help.

Comment: Hi we can't help without seeing the relevant code. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I dont know how to show the code as its buildt with wordpress/elementor..

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see the code being created?

Comment: I found only 1 solution, and I posted it as an answer, but thanks for atleast commenting mr Haworth,  I really do appreciate it, maybe you can give me some feedback if that is a bad solution or not.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there is an issue with Elementor regarding Safari and containers.

I tried making a new container, just containing 2 images but same happened, didnt really matter what I did.

Solution:

1.
Add a "html" element inside a container, and manually construct the header.

Here is the code I used:

```html
<header style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;  padding: 20px; color: #fff; width: 100%;">

      <a href="/"><img src="LOGO_URL.WEBP" alt="Logo" style="width: 286px; height: 54px; object-fit: contain; padding-bottom: 10px;"></a>

      <a href="#navbar"><img src="BARS.webp" alt="Menu Icon" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; object-fit: contain; margin-left: auto;"></a>

    </header>
```

2.

As I use a POPUP in Elementor for the mobile menu, I chose the popup and went into the popup settings in elementor (bottom left side)
Then Advanced > Advanced > Open By Selector, where I typed "a[href="#navbar"]"

Then I could link the BARS picture to the popup with `<a href="#navbar"></a>`

So that was my solution, couldent find anything else considering Elementor doesnt let you exactly edit the code it outputs.

Cheers,
Andree